# cannot to insert data into mysql table

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc, netbeans

```
    if(request.getParameter("btn_register")!=null)  //check condition button register click event not null "btn_register"
    {
        String firstname,lastname,email,password,role; //create blank bariable

        firstname=request.getParameter("txt_firstname");    //textbox name "txt_fristname"
        lastname=request.getParameter("txt_lastname");  //textbox name "txt_lastname"
        email=request.getParameter("txt_email");    //textbox name "txt_email"
        password=request.getParameter("txt_password");  //textbox name "txt_password"
        role=request.getParameter("txt_role"); //select option name "txt_role"

        String dburl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp_multiuser_login_db"; //database url string the "jsp_multiuser_login_db" is database name
        String dbuname="root"; //database username   
        String dbpwd ="root"; //database password

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //load driver
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,dbuname,dbpwd); //create connection

            PreparedStatement pstmt=null; //create statement

            pstmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email=? "); //sql select query
            pstmt.setString(1,email); 
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and set in ResultSet object "rs".

            if(rs.next())
            {
                String checkEmail=rs.getString("email");

                if(email.equals(checkEmail))    //check condition email already exist from user email
                {
                    request.setAttribute("errorMsg", "sorry email already exist"); //error message for email already exist
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pstmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tbl_user(firstname,lastname,email,password,role) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"); //sql insert query
                pstmt.setString(1,firstname);
                pstmt.setString(2,lastname);
                pstmt.setString(3,email);           //set all variables
                pstmt.setString(4,password);
                pstmt.setString(5,role);
                pstmt.executeUpdate(); //execute query

                request.setAttribute("successMsg", "register successfully please login account"); //register successfully message
            }

            pstmt.close();  //close statement 
            con.close(); //close connection
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
```

I'm unable to insert data into my workbench SQL database. My database name is jsp_multiuser_login_db and there's a table inside it called tbl_user with 6 columns: id, firstname,lastname,email,password and role. //////////////

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What is the exception or error? Also, this code is in a **jsp**?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nothing happens it just loads the register.jsp page  again.

Comment: Are you able to execute Query?

Comment: @sc0der it doesn't show any error , but no data is inserted into the database.

Comment: And what happens when you try inserting an email address with workbench, and then inserting it again with your "register.jsp"; btw, model 1 JSPs have been deprecated for ~20 years. Model 2 JSPs have been obsolete for about 10 years. Thymeleaf and JSF seem to be the modern Java web view technologies. Have you considered refactoring your code?

Comment: @sammy I want to make sure that there is a connection to the Database and able to query.

Answer (score 0):

When executing try just

```
pstmt.execute(); //execute query
```

Comment: Which means you are inserting any other type of data which is not same as in database

Comment: Check datatypes at both ends

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and everything worked fine: [Mysql Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zehGk.png)

There are two possible issues may be preventing your code from submitting to database:

1. Invalid credentials or not able to connect, please check `con.isClosed()` to check if you have open connection.
2. Invalid library. please validate your imports as java.sql as follows:

   - `import java.sql.Connection;`
   - `import java.sql.DriverManager;`
   - `import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`
   - `import java.sql.ResultSet;`